# SQL Case Decimal Between

Tags: sql, t-sql

In my database I have an entry like: 'V2.0.0.0 VersionData'
I need my case statement to look at this value, trim off from the space onwards and remove the V at the start leaving '2.0.0.0, the case statement should then return 'Pass' if its greater than 2.0.1.0 else 'Fail'

This is what I have so far but it doesnt work:

```
Select
    CASE 
    When (Select 
        Convert(Decimal(4,4), 
            REPLACE(
                LEFT(EntryValue, 
                    CHARINDEX(' ', EntryValue) - 1),'v','')) 
        from table where entrytype = 'VERSION') BETWEEN 0 and 2.1 THEN 'Pass'
         Else 'Fail'
    END [V-Check]
```

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text!

Comment: Table:
EntryType              EntryValue
VERSION               v2.0.0.0 Version Data

Both columns are varchar

And sorry whats the difference between case expression and case statement
(I cant get this response to format the way I want it to sorry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that

```
declare @EntryValue varchar(250)='V2.0.0.0 VersionData'
Select REPLACE(LEFT(@EntryValue,CHARINDEX(' ', @EntryValue) - 1),'v','')
--2.0.0.0
```

You do not have a string that can be intepreted like a decimal.
Without knowing how your version numbering Works, a solution can not be found,
For instance is V2.11.0.0 possible? If so, then is V2.5.0.0 a a lower or higher version? 
If you convert 2.11.0.0 to the decimal 2.11 then it will be lower than 2.5
In what I think would be the default intepretation of the version number, you do not have a single number, but 4 numbers you have to compare consecutively to get a result.

One of many ways to parse out the numbers in the version would then be:

```
declare @EntryValue varchar(250)='V2.0.0.0 VersionData'
;with cte as
(
select charindex('.',@EntryValue) p1
,charindex('.',@EntryValue,charindex('.',@EntryValue)+1) p2
,charindex('.',@EntryValue,charindex('.',@EntryValue,charindex('.',@EntryValue)+1)+1) p3
,charindex(' ',@EntryValue) p4
)
select substring(@EntryValue,2,p1-2)+0 [MajorVersion]
,SUBSTRING(@EntryValue,p1+1,p2-p1-1)+0 [MinorVersion]
,SUBSTRING(@EntryValue,p2+1,p3-p2-1)+0 [BugFixRelease]
,SUBSTRING(@EntryValue,p3+1,p4-p3-1)+0 [Build]
from cte
```

If the numbers cannot be larger than 10, then you have an easy task, then you can just use a simple compare

```
select case when 'V2.1.0.0 VersionData'>= 'V2.0.1.0 VersionData' then 1 else 0 end
```

Since the lexicographical ordering of the characters would ensure that the result is correct.

> -- Added in edit

If you have up to 4 numbers in your version, then you can abuse the internal function PARSENAME to get the numbers in an easier fashion:

```
declare @EntryValue varchar(250)='V2.0.0.0 VersionData'
select 
    parsename(stuff(left(@EntryValue,charindex(' ',@EntryValue)),1,1,''),4)+0 MajorVersion
    , parsename(stuff(left(@EntryValue,charindex(' ',@EntryValue)),1,1,''),3)+0 MinorVersion
    , parsename(stuff(left(@EntryValue,charindex(' ',@EntryValue)),1,1,''),2)+0 Release
    , parsename(stuff(left(@EntryValue,charindex(' ',@EntryValue)),1,1,''),1)+0 Build
```

Comment: It was as simple as 
select case when 'V2.1.0.0 VersionData'>= 'V2.0.1.0 VersionData' then 1 else 0 end 
I dont quite fully understand why it works though with the text in there as well as the numbers

Comment: It Works because the when you compare text you compare the internal representation. For instance in ASCII the character '1' is represented as the number 49, while '0' is 48. Normally the ordering in the chrarcter table follows the ordering you would expect. Notice though that in ASCII, as well as other codepages, 'A' is 65, while 'a' is 97. The string comparison Works because a string comparison compares the first charachter in string 1 to the first character in string 2. If they are equal, it continues to character 2, the 3 etc, until a difference is found.

Comment: However notice that "select case when 'V2.1.0.0 This Version'>= 'V2.1.0.0 Versiondata' then 1 else 0 end" returns 0, because even though the version numbers are the same, the text is not, and "  select case when 'V2.13.0.0 Versiondata'>= 'V2.5.0.0 Versiondata' then 1 else 0 end  " returns 0, because the number 1 in 13 is smaller than 5.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that converting a string '2.0.1.0', which contains several `.`-characters will not properly convert into `2010` (as you might intend).

However, if you can guarantee that you always have exactly 4 version parts and each version part is between `0..9`, i.e. there is no version like, for example, `2.0.11.0' or`2.0.1.0.9', then the following solution should work. It simply relies on the order of string values, which - above mentioned restriction concerning version parts guaranteed - is just as if you compared integral values:

```sql
with versions as
( select entryValue, Substring(LEFT(EntryValue, 
                    CHARINDEX(' ', EntryValue)),2,100) as versionStr
  from (values
        ('V2.0.0.0 some older version'),
        ('V2.0.1.0 sufficient version'),
        ('V2.0.1.9 newer version')

       ) as versionTable(entryValue)
)
select *, (case when versionStr >= '2.0.1.0' then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end) as "check"
from versions;
```